# OpenGL won't draw polygons for objects not in namespace

Tags: c++, opengl

I have made a class with a drawing function .draw(), which will draw that object on the screen.  This function works fine for a named global variable, but not for one allocated on the heap or placed in an array.

This is the code in the file with main():

```
Object obj1 = Object::Object (SCALE);

Object obj2 = Object::Object (SCALE);
Object* objPtr2;

Object* objPtr3;

Object objArray [5];

void init (void)
{
    //...
    objPtr2 = &obj2;
    objPtr3 = new Object (SCALE);
    objArray [0] = Object::Object (SCALE);
    //...
}

void display (void)
{
    //...
    obj1.draw();            // Draws polygons
    objPtr2->draw();        // Draws polygons
    objPtr3->draw();        // POINTs only
    objArray [0].draw();    // POINTs only
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem.  In my constructor I was only declaring a starting rotation, not initializing it.
I'm used to java, which would automatically initialize to zero, so I didn't catch the bug.

Worth noting: C++ will initiate integers, floats or doubles to zero for static objects, which is what was causing the discrepancy.  Dynamic initialization was leaving garbage in the fields for the rotation.  Not anything to do with the namespace or using the Heap for dynamic memory storage.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors you are passing to `glMaterialfv()` do not have enough values:

```
float wh [] = {1, 1, 1};
glBegin ( GL_POINTS);
glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, wh);
```

This call expects a vector with **four** values (see [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMaterial.xml) here). So this call will use undefined memory content for the 4th component, which defines the alpha value. This might explain "random" objects not being drawn.

The call should look like this instead:

```
float wh[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, wh);
```

There is a second call here, where the definition of the variable is not shown. It might have the same problem:

```
glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, color );
```

Comment: OK, I did have four values defined for the color array.  I changed the float wh[] to have a fourth element, and the behavior hasn't changed much.  That part of code is only displaying the point as a placeholder for me to verify that everything else is working correctly.  I edited my question.  Thanks for the reply.